# Spark_Excel skipping leading rows on Databricks - reading from ADLS gen 1 - need other options or a solution to my specific case

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to read from an ADLS Gen 1 storage folder and trying to write into ADLS Gen 1 as well.

I have Databricks code that reads the excel files from ADLS Gen 1 using spark_excel.

```
spark_df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("dataAddress", "'Sheet1'!B1:C3").option("header", False).load('/mnt/adls/+path')
```

What I require is to have the dataAddress index B1:C3 be specified by a variable.
Something like:

```
var_A = 'B1'
var B = 'C3'
spark_df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("dataAddress", "'Sheet1'!var_A:var_B").option("header", False).load('/mnt/adls/+path')
```

If this is not possible, is there any other way to read an excel file into a dataframe from ADLS Gen 1?

Answer (score 0):

**ADLS Gen1 is a depreciated Azure service. On Feb 29, 2024 Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 will be retired.** If you use Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1, make sure to **migrate to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2** prior to that date. To learn how, see [Migrate Azure Data Lake Storage from Gen1 to Gen2 by using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-migrate-gen1-to-gen2-azure-portal).

Once you will migrate to the ADLS Gen2, you can use Python pandas module to read the Excel file and then convert pandas dataframe to spark datagrame.

Refer below code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pandas as pd

# path to your file
filepath = '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/sample.xlsx'

company_pd_df = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name='Company')

companiesSchema = StructType([
  StructField("CompanyID", IntegerType(), False),
  StructField("CompanyName", StringType(), False),
  StructField("Description", StringType(), False)])

companies_spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(company_pd_df, schema=companiesSchema)
```

Refer the snippet below for the output of the above code for better understanding.

[image]

Note that:

1. While convert Pandas DataFrame into Spark DataFrame, we need to manually define the Schema, otherwise the conversion will fail probably.
2. In some cases, the created Spark DataFrame may display some dummy data or additional unnecessary row. In this case, we may filter out those unnecessary rows. e.g. companies_Df = companies_df.filter(isnan(“CompaniesID”) != True)